# In Warcraft 3 Reign of Chaos a night elf AI took control of my units, how?

Tags: warcraft-3

I decided to see if my old warcraft 3 discs would work on my modern windows 10 pc. I installed reign of chaos, which had no issues (other than the installation window thinking I had windows nt installed). I was able to open up the game and did a test game against the AI to see if the game ran fine. It appears to, but I had something weird happen that I never had happen before!

I was playing undead (the race I used to always pick) and set the AI to night elf. I chose plunder isle as my map. I lost that game (haven't played in so long I didn't know what to do). What was weird though is when the Ai was leveling my base, I noticed that it had my abominations and frost wyrm under its control! I don't understand how it could've done that. Only banshees have the ability to take control of units, and I've never seen any other race do that! I don't understand what happened. Did the game glitch on me or did the bot get some lucky drop that let it take control of my units?

As for heroes, the bot chose keeper and demonhunter. Neither of those have the ability to take control of units, and looking on Mojo Stormstout, there is NO mention of any item or ability on a night elf unit that can do that!

edit: Oh, and this was in Reign of Chaos, just to be clear. I haven't even tried to install The Frozen Throne yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no mechanic, which allows a night elf player to take control of your units. I can only imagine the use of a Scroll of animate dead - revives 6 dead units to fight for you for 120 seconds. Could have resurrected a dead abonimation and frost wyrm.

I recommend you check the replay.

Comment: This was also the only thing I could come up with

Comment: I didn't save the replay, so I can't go back and see. When I saw he had my abominations and my frost wyrm, I had assumed that he took control of them during the fight somehow. Your answer does explain how on earth a night elf was able to take control of some of my units. Though oddly enough, I don't think he took my crypt fiends (though I didn't really look it over, I just quit the match as soon as I was defeated and saw he had some of my units!).

Comment: Animate dead doesn't discriminate between friendly and hostile and randomly chooses between all dead units in a the area, if there are more than six. It's entirely possible the spell resurrected just abos and wyrms from you as well as a few night elf units.

Comment: Wyrms don't leave a body, do they? (Since they're flying)